# How to use authentication with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, frameworks

recently I began to create a REST API with Django REST Framework. I want to implement an authentication system but I have several doubts (The tutorial provided by the Framework is not so concise).

I'd like that every users that want access to my API need a token. These are my questions:

- Would I need to create a model which keeps the users data? (User, email, token, etc)
- How can I relate each model with each user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea is to use [token authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication). It works with default djangos `User` model out-of-the-box and doesn't need to create any other models. When you create an instance of `User` you pass an email along with the password and create an instance of `Token` that is bound to newly created instance of `User`. So:

1. No, the models are already shipped with Django.
2. You just need to establish a relationship.

If you need to keep any other data related to `User` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)'s a piece of documentation you need. Have a look [here](https://github.com/codepotpl/codepot-backend/blob/master/codepot/views/auth/_sign_up.py) as well. This is how creating an `User` instance along with the `Token` is created in codepot.pl workshops backend.